# Over-Ear Headphones with detachable cable

Tags: headphones

I am looking for headphones with a detachable cable, so that I can replace the cable when it breaks and get a longer / shorter cable.

I had the Sennheiser HD 201 (about 22 Euro) before and was quite happy with them, except that the cable now broke.

I had the Bose QuietComfort 25 (about 250 Euro) and was not happy with them. I wanted them because of the noise canceling, but it turned out that the pressure on my ears / the noise of the speakers when it is very silent in my room were not worth that much money for me.

I use the headphones when I am watching movies or when I lie in bed and listen to audio books / music. They should be really comfortable.

The audio quality of the HD 201 was ok for me, I guess. They are already quite comfortable to wear, but the Bose Quiet Comfort 25 were a bit better.

An option to use them wireless with my computer would be nice.

Comment: Whats your budget?

Comment: @PeterZhu That depends really heavily on what I get. I guess not more than 300 Euro, but when it doesn't offer something significantly better than the HD 201, then not more than 75 Euro.

Comment: Keep using HD 201 and learn to solder. Replacing a cable is super-easy, and basic soldering irons are cheap. The headphones are cheap, so you'll feel comfortable messing them up. OR ask someone who can solder to shorten the broken wire to 3cm. This way you'll get detachable cable.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest the **[Denon AC-GC20](http://usa.denon.com/us/product/bluetooth/sportsheadphones/ahgc20)**.

- [About **300€** in Germany](http://geizhals.de/denon-ah-gc20-a1152016.html)
- **Over-Ear**
- **Detachable cable**
- **Bluetooth Smart**
- Supports modern codecs
- [aptX Low Latency](http://www.aptx.com/) (High quality audio over Bluetooth)
- Active noise canceling (can be turned off)
- Dual mode (connect two devices at the same time)
- Very good sound quality and frequency response
- 20h playback time (Bluetooth)
- usable with dead battery

I highly recommend these headphones to everyone who asks my for recommendations for headphones in general. I was searching for Bluetooth headphones myself and they are the only ones that feature everything I could ask for.

Answer (score 2):

## Marshall Headphones

[Marshall](https://www.marshallheadphones.com) offers headphones with detachable cord.

> The detachable double-ended coil cord with mic and remote is equipped with an L-plug end, providing improved durability and carrying ease. The dual 3.5 mm jacks allow you to choose which side you prefer to wear your cable on or to plug in and share your music with a friend.

See the upper right corner panel in this picture.

[image]
<sub>(source: [theawesomer.com](http://theawesomer.com/photos/2015/01/marshall_major_ii_headphones_1.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the [Monster DNAs](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Monster-DNA-On-Ear-Headphones-Carbon-Fiber-Black/dp/B00E7L2LQE/ref=pd_cp_23_1?ie=UTF8&refRID=0262VMS7EYW02KV3SEBV) for about £100 so around 130 euros, these headphones are a comfortable set of on-ear headphones, with a tangle free detatchable cable. They are made of plastic, however they are extremely sturdy and will bend to almost straight without being damaged. The pieces are designed to pop out before snapping allowing easy reassembly.

They also look pretty cool, available in a range of colours and come in a nice box with travel bag. Another cool feature of these is the Music sharing feature, the headphones have 2 3.5mm jacks in series, so if you have music playing through your headphones, someone else can plug their headphones into yours and you can both listen to the same track.

Another suggestion are the [Audio-Technica-ATH-M50X](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Audio-Technica-ATH-M50X-Monitor-Professional-Headphones/dp/B00HVLUR86) over ear headphones. I have a friend that ahd a pair of these and he said they were amazing for the price (£88 on amazon currently). They have thick cushioned ear pads so comfortable, 3 removable cables (1.5m/3.0m/1.5-3.0m coiled). [Cnet](http://www.cnet.com/uk/products/audio-technica-ath-m50x/) have a good detailed revie wont hese and they are also the best seller son amazon currently in the UK.

Comment: The headphones you've linked are not over-ear, but on-ear headphones.

Comment: Sorry I missed that requirement(I know it is obvious and in the title!) they are still pretty comfortable however and good sound isolation.

Comment: I have added a second suggestion also

Comment: +1 for ATH-M50X because I have been using this since May 2014 and the quality/price is one of the best that I have seen so far. Mine still look really new. Two of my co-workers also have the same headphones. As a programmer/DJ, it is really comfortable for long periods of listening.

For American viewers of this question, check out [this Amazon link here](http://www.amazon.com/Audio-Technica-ATH-M50x-Professional-Monitor-Headphones/dp/B00HVLUR86)

Answer (score 1):

**AKG Y50** are your friends:

- Detacheable cable
- low price ~100€
- dedicated, clear sound quality
- comfortable even for longer use

Answer (score 0):

I am very satisfied with these "NC-25" headphones
[https://www.amazon.com/Cancelling-Headphones-Bluetooth-Wireless-Srhythm/dp/B0797NS5WB](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0797NS5WB)
They are both Bluetooth or wired (with detachable cable), easy to use, foldable, over-ear, have noise-canceling, come with a classy compact sturdy case, cost 59.99$

I wear them most of the time when working, without music, only for the quietness of noise-canceling.
I also found that they help a lot to get some rest during long distance travel, etc